# Interface inheritance - What about unused methods?

Tags: java

I have the following situation, namely: I created the Calculator class and then two Conventional and Scientific interfaces. The Conventional interface has the following methods:

```
interface ConventionalCalculator {

    abstract public void addition(double number);
    abstract public void subtraction(double number);
    abstract public void multiplication(double number);
    abstract public void division(double number);
    abstract public void percent(double number);

}

interface ScientificCalculator extends ConventionalCalculator {
    abstract public void mod(double number);

// anothers methods...
}
```

Then the Scientific interface inherits the Conventional interface, because I want it to have methods addition, subtraction, multiplication, disivion and its own methods. The problem is that the Scientific Interface will also inherit the percent () method that it will not use at all. How could I solve this problem with the percent () method? Should I create some additional interface? Or maybe nothing prevents the Scientific interface from inheriting the percent () method even though it won't use it?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to use abstract public in an interface, now answering your question, you have to see the interface as a contract, it forces a class to follow and implement that contract. In your case, you can create a parent interface for the calculator with the common contract and create different implementations for the calculator from this common contract.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a common parent interface called `Calculator`, which will contain the common methods. Then extend it with `ConventionalCalculator` and `ScientificCalculator`.